# Table structure for inventory management in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a little stuck with the inventory table design and would appreciate if anyone could guide me with that.

The inventory is at 3 different locations(warehouses). I want help with how do I avoid creating multiple itemcodes for each warehouse

The current set up is as follows: -

#### table no 1 - `inventory_T`

- itemcode(primary key)
- item name
- item group id(foreign key to item group table)
- item category id(foreign key to item category table)

#### table no 2 - `item_costs`

- itemcode(fk to table 1)
- average cost

#### table no 3 - `stock_balance`

- itemcode(fk to table 1)
- stock on hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a single database which serves all warehouses.

Create another table

> warehouses

- warehouseid (PK)
- name
- other details

And then add the field
  - warehouseid 
to table stock_balance as a FK(Foreign Key) - this way you will bind each stock of an item to a warehouse

Comment: thanks. now i am developing the sales invoice and for the item selection i m able to pull database items to the select combo box. how do i allow multiple selections and then pass them to another form for further processing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to describe your problem:

How can I store the information about **items** so that I know **how many** are at **each location**?

The three things in bold are the key pieces of information. Which means, we need to be able to keep track of locations and items and everything that can be different for a given location. Everything else about the items we store in the *items* table. Everything else about the location we store in the locations table. The above problem description says only the amount stored is different, but it can be for your problem that other things about the items are different, modify as needed.

I would go as follows:

#### Table: Items

- Item ID
- Item name
- Item price
- .... various other interesting properties

#### Table: Warehouses

- Warehouse ID
- Warehouse name
- .... various other interesting properties

#### Table: stock

- Item ID (fk to Items)
- Warehouse ID (fk to Warehouses)
- Quantity

**Note**: Item ID and Warehouse ID combined is the primary key.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response Mel. i have done the following. pl. correct me if i am doing wrong. i have created one table for item masters which has itemcode-pk and item price. the other table is items warehouse which has itemcode-fk, warehouseid-fk and quantity. the warehouse id and itemcode is concantenated primary key. which will disallow any itemcode to be stored more than once in any warehouse. is this structure ok.